# Why am I getting RPC timeouts during sqlCommand inserts on new server?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, tfs, rpc, sqlcommand

We're migrating our databases to an offsite data center that contains newer more robust servers. I have a process that imports data from my application to our local sql server and it works great. However, I've moved my database to the new server and I am **periodically** receiving RPC timeout errors or cannot errors that state it can't make an RPC call.

The old sql server really only contained my database and a couple of other custom application databases. That said, the new server is hosting other databases as well as our Sharepoint database and Team Foundation Server database. While looking at the SQL Profiler, I notice many frequent RPC calls from a TFSService even though no one is using TFS at the time. Similarly, Sharepoint is constantly connecting through RPC as well, but unlike TFS, people are actively using it.

To me, those databases should be either by themselves or together on their own sql server. Am I wrong? Do you think the RPC calls from TFS and Sharepoint could be hogging my connection? If that's the case and if I'm not permitted to move the database and the another sql server, is there a way to configure TFS and Sharepoint to tone down the amount of "needless" interactions to the database? Any other ideas I should look for?

By the way, I've received this error from my machine as well as a from a virtual machine that exists in the data center so I don't think it's a connection (distance) issue.

Thank You.

Comment: It would help if you could provide actual error messages and more details on the version of TFS, SharePoint & SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Team Foundation Server 2010 has a notifications system built-in (not to be confused with the events/alerts system that sends E-Mail or SOAP events).

Each application tier periodically polls a table in the Tfs_Configuration database asking "has there been any notifications that I'm subscribed to happen since I last checked?". An example of a notification is when somebody changes a configuration setting, all the application tiers pick up that change almost immediately without having to restart.

In the SQL Profiler, this will look like a lot of activity and load on your server, but it's really not.